# How to Publish .Net solution containing multiple projects through Visual Studio to Azure

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-web-app-service, web-deployment

I'm having a .Net Solution with 2 Projects. I've created a webapp in azure for deployment. So, i downloaded publishsetting file from Azure webapp.

Is there anyway to publish the entire solution[multiple projects] to that webapp using downloaded publishsettings file.

I see that only one project can be published to azure. Please suggest

Comment: Are your two projects separate web applications? Or is one project a supporting project for your single web application that you're trying to publish?

Comment: Two Separate Web Applications

Comment: There are several options to do so. Do you want them: 1. Both hosted on the same Azure Web App, each with different domain names, such as customdomain1.com and customdomain2.com? 2. Do you want one as a virtual application beneath another, such as foo.azurewebsites.net and foo.azurewebsites.net/virtual-app-1? 3. Or do you want to publish them to different slots within the same Web App?

Comment: Preference
1.Host on same Azure WebApp w.r.to., different slots
2.Host on same Azure WebApp w.r.to different domain names.

Suggestions are most welcome in both cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hosting on the same Azure Web App with different slots**

First, you'll need to define your second slot. This can be done in the portal by navigating to your Web App's management blade, then clicking the Deployment Slots menu option. Once a slot is defined, you can click on it under the Deployment Slots menu, and you'll be taken to a totally separate Overview tab for the slot. Note that on this page, you can download a totally separate Publish Profile for the slot.

With two web applications in the same Visual Studio solution, you can right click on each, choose "Publish", then use a primary or slot publish profile to determine where each web application will be published.

**Multiple custom domain names for different web applications in one Azure Web App**

Use the same steps as above. After publishing both of your sites (using two slots - the primary and the new slot you define), browse to the Custom Domains tab in each slot. Here, you can set up each custom domain so that Azure will route traffic to the appropriate slot accordingly.

Comment: It worked out. Thank you.

How about the condition if Solution has multiple projects which are inter-related [O/p of a project is I/p of another ... or... BL/DL/...]. Please suggest on this as well.